Can a Ger Toshav observe Shabbat?
I’m curious if a Ger Toshav is allowed to observe Shabbat according to Halacha, general Noahides/gentiles to my understanding are prohibited from it, however I’ve heard that the Halacha might be different, although I haven’t looked into any Sugyot regarding it so I’m curious if anybody here can confirm. If the answer is yes, they are allowed to observe it, is it optional or mandatory, and would it be the same Halacha as Shabbat for a Jew?

https://www.sefaria.org/Keritot.9a.12?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all

https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.14.8?lang=bi

see here https://baisdovyosef.com/3231-a-strange-acceptance-of-kabbolas-shabboswww-frumtoronto-com/

Credit to @schmerel for some of the sources here, taken from here:
Those who obligate a גר תושב to keep Shabbat:

Rashi Yevamot 48b
"Ohel Mordechai quotes the Ponovicher Rov adding that since for Bnai Yisroel the desecration of Shabbos is tantamount to serving Avoda Zarah (Chullin 5a), so it is for a Ger Toshav, and therefore he has to observe Shabbat."

Those who don't obligate a גר תושב to keep Shabbat:

Tosafot Yevamot 48b ד״ה זה גר
Rambam Hilchot Shabbat 20:14
Ramban Yevamot 48b ד"ה הגר זה וכו
Rashba שם ד״ה הגר זה
Ritva שם ד"ה הגר זה
Meiri שם ד"ה עבד שמל
Mishna Berura (304: 1)
Rav Yehudah bar Yakar פירוש התפלות והברכות, מהודרת שמואל ירושלמי, ירושלים, תשל"ט, עמ' קו (he adds that there is also no איסור for him to keep shabbat)

With regards to the specifics of what type of גר תושב we are talking about, see here and here.
Also according to those who say he is chaiv to keep Shabbat like Rashi and others I may have missed, I haven't seen anyone who makes a chiluk between the Jew's shabbat and גר תושב shabbat, since besides for a potential גר we either keep shabbat fully or not at all.

The thing about a Ger Toshav is that the rules for them are different because they live in the Eretz Yisrael.  I don't really know how it works for a Noahide within the state of Israel.  I'm following this thread so that when someone with more knowledge answers, I can learn a thing or two.
However, I know that outside Israel, the rules are not so strict.  As long as a goy is not observing Shabbat in the same manners as a Jew, they seem to be okay.  It's kind of like how someone going through the process of conversion keeps all the Shabbat rules, but deliberately breaks at least one, since they are not yet a Jew.
